# dir global name not defined (py2 to py3 migration)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a code like :

try:

```
import clka.api as api
print(clka.__file__)
print(dir(clka))
```

I am getting global name not defined.I want to get the list of functions in clka.

ANY HELP!

Comment: Please provide the full traceback.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular how to [ask]. Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. After doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck, which can help you get better answers.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't import the package you're trying to inspect.

```
import clka
print(dir(clka))
```